# is there an easy way to have a UITableView highlight which row is selected to a user via a disclosure indicator?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, accessorytype

is there an easy way to have a UITableView highlight which row is selected to a user via a disclosure indicator?

That if row 3 was selected then after row 10 was selected (only one row can be selected at a time say), then:

1. disclosure indicator for row 3 should disappear
2. disclosure indicator for row 10 should then appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one , here count_of_rows is the count of array from which you are populating the table .

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
 {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    for(int i=0 ; i < count_of_rows ; i++)
    {
        if(i != selectedRow)
        {
                     UITableViewCell * c= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1]]
                     c.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to just iterate over "tableView.visibleCells"? Or is it necessary to go through all orws?  what is your count_of_rows definition?

Comment: count_of_rows is the array count from which you populate the table . If you are not populating the table from any array , count_of_rows would be the no of rows in your table.  You can try with tableView.visibleCells also but I am not sure how it responds to reusable cell .... You may get more than once cell being highlighted . Just have a try ...

Comment: Here if you scroll the tableview cells, you would get unexpected results. Some other row will show the disclosure indicator.

Comment: Gomsthi is right, this answer is good except you also need to store the selected row index path in an ivar and use this to set/clear the accessory view in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I guess if you save it as an ivar you don't need to loop through all rows then, as you'll know the one that has to be switched off no?

Answer (score 0):

use this function and get index path of row and column

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // int x =  indexPath.row ;

    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];   
}
```